# Post textarea value to controller using ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send the value of `<textarea>` to a method in some controller but doesn't run well. I will post the code to make it clear:

Here is the method

```
public ActionResult SubmitText(string txtRendered)
```

and here is the ajax to call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Form/SubmitText',
    type: 'Get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { txtRendered: $("textarea#render").val() },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

**and here is the textarea**

```
<textarea id="render" name="txtRenderd" class="span6">
    <form class="form-horizontal" >
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Form Name</legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="textinput-0">Text Input</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="textinput-0" name="textinput-0" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
                    <p class="help-block">help</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</textarea>
```

actually it is complicated, since I am trying to pass a form as a text as you can see

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: there is no error but it does not send the parameter but if i change the textarea value to something like '1 ', it pass it @StephenMuecke

Comment: Show your html for the textarea

Comment: Change the "type: 'Get'," to type: 'POST', Also add HTTPPOST on the Action method

Comment: just a moment @StephenMuecke

Comment: see the edition plz @StephenMuecke

Comment: Your html makes no sense (and its not valid). Why do you have a `<form>` and other inputs inside a `<textarea>`?

Comment: It is hard to explain but I need to get the form elements @StephenMuecke

Comment: You only have one input (a `type="text"`). Delete the enclosing `<textarea>` and post back the value of the input - `data: { txtRendered: $('#textinput-0').val() },`

Comment: do you mean to change textarea to text? @StephenMuecke

Comment: No, I mean delete it.